# Why jQuery sometimes overwrites window.onbeforeunload?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, onbeforeunload

I am having strange problem with jQuery (1.6.x). I have this simple call on my page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return 'Are you sure ?'; };
```

But it doesn't work, because as I've found out, jQuery overwrites content of the `window.onbeforeunload`. In JS console, I can see that `window.onbeforeunload` contains piece of jQuery code:

```
function( e ) {
// Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
// when an event is called after a page has unloaded
return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && (!e || jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type) ?
    jQuery.event.handle.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) : undefined;
};
```

Is there a way I can find why and where jQuery overwrites my `onbeforeunload` function? When I try to run empty jsfiddle with just jQuery loaded and with my `onbeforeunload` function, it works as expected.

Any hints will be appreciated.

EDIT:

Just in case, somebody suggests using:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { return 'Are you sure';} );
```

I've already tried it and it behaves the same way as using pure Javascript.

Comment: Can you use the jQuery `unload` method instead? http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: I am able to successfully apply my own function to `onbeforeunload` and I use jQuery 1.6. Is there any more information or code you can provide? Does this not work in all browsers? http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/QgVE8/

Comment: You're screaming in space. Provide a test case that reproduces this problem and we can help.

Comment: Marcus Ekwall: Yeah, I know and I'm sorry. It's a pretty big intranet webapp and it's practically impossible for me to show it publicly. Therefore I am just looking for hints what should I check or how should I disable this jQuery behaviour...

Comment: Not an answer in it's entirety, but I just found that this happens after I append some elements to the document with .prepend(). When I remove them using .remove() onbeforeunload works again. I wonder if jquery changes the window object somehow when things are added after loading. In any case the chosen solution here works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've finally figured a solution, which is probably not the cleanest one - because I don't know the exact cause of the problem - but it works. I've put my beforeunload function into jQuery's load function so it is executed after DOM and other elements are loaded.

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { return 'Are you sure ?';} );
});
```

Comment: this $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { return 'Are you sure ?';} ); just worked fine for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck trying a `setTimeout(function(){ ... },0)`, I ran into the same problem and this worked as a viable solution.